# c# read html file and convert to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, pdf

I convert small html strings to pdf like this:

```
// set a path to where you want to write the PDF to.
string sPathToWritePdfTo = @"path\new_pdf.pdf";

System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sbHtml.Append("<html>");
sbHtml.Append("<html>");
sbHtml.Append("<body>");
sbHtml.Append("<font size='14'> my first pdf</font>");
sbHtml.Append("<br />");
sbHtml.Append("this is my pdf!!!!");
sbHtml.Append("</body>");
sbHtml.Append("</html>");

// create file stream to PDF file to write to
using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream
            (sPathToWritePdfTo, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    // create new instance of Pdfizer
    Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdf = new Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter();

    // open stream to write Pdf to to
    htmlToPdf.Open(stream);

    // write the HTML to the component
    htmlToPdf.Run(sbHtml);

    // close the write operation and complete the PDF file
    htmlToPdf.Close();
```

I wonder i can make the above conversion for big html strings,without using the append method.I tried this line:

```
string sbHtml=File.ReadAllText("mypath/pdf.html");
```

Instead of this line:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
```

but it didn't work:I had an exception in line:

```
     htmlToPdf.Run(sbHtml);
```

"xmlexception was unhandled bu user code

I also have to mention that the path i read the html file is from my pc!!
It's not from a server or anything else.I would like to get asnwers for both paths.

Comment: And by `it didn't work` you mean?

Comment: How did it fail? Did you get an exception? If so, what was the exception? Was your string empty after trying to do the read? Is your HTML valid?

Comment: i had an exception.you can look in my edited post.Thanks!

Comment: Does the `sbHtml` that you read from the file contain the html-text that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the converter has an overload for string, you can simply use:

```
  htmlToPdf.Run(File.ReadAllText(@"mypath/pdf.html"));
```

If not and accepts only StringBuilder:

```
  System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sbHtml.Append(File.ReadAllText(@"mypath/pdf.html"));
```

Comment: i had an http exception because my path is in my pc.Sorry not to mention that before.You can see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();    
sbHtml.Append(File.ReadAllText("mypath/pdf.html"));
```

Comment: No,i still have the exception mentioned in the end of my post

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the exception, make sure the HTML is valid XHTML. PDFizer requires valid XHTML.